# nodejs - call functions in order after termination of the previous using Promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to call functions call2() and then call3() in this order, so that call3() is called only when call2() terminates. I am using Promise to achieve that.

But call3() is called before call2() terminates. Here is my code:

```
function call2() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("calling 2");
            resolve(true);
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function call3() {
    console.log("calling 3");    
}

call2().then(call3());
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, or could not understand how to use promise. Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `then(call3())` you are calling the *call3* function rather than passing it as a callback, change to this:

```
call2().then(call3);
```

```js
function call2() {
   console.log('Start...');
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("calling 2");
            resolve(true);
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function call3() {
    console.log("calling 3");    
}

call2().then(call3);
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your call3 into the function:

```
call2().then(()=>call3());
```